# Any gag items in water level?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

Partway through the water level (Act 4 Chapter 6) the sub encounters turbulence and gets swept up along with trees, mines, and other debris.

I *thought* I saw something like a toilet or kitchen sink but looking at [other player videos](http://youtu.be/0baIUUCefS0?t=8m19s), it appears it might have just been a tree.

Are there any gag items or easter eggs that float past the submarine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your [toilet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c6A2CwgD1A&hd=1&t=6m9s), but other than that, it's just debris in the whirlpool part. The only other identifiable object appears to be [a hull door](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c6A2CwgD1A&hd=1&t=5m37s).

[image: toilet]

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I played through it again and didn't see anything strange. It definitely was my imagination on that first run.

Comment: @AlvinReyes: Actually, it wasn't your imagination. I did a run today and had to change my answer (from nearly a year ago now). I still haven't seen anything else, though

Comment: Woot, validation!